# My question is about ways to build a growing multidimensional list (array) in Dart

Tags: list, multidimensional-array, dart

Is there a way to build growing dart multidimensional lists? The only method I found was to use temporary lists, as below:

```
void main() {
  List<List<int>> list = [];
  List<int> listTemp = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      listTemp.add(i * j);
    }
    list.add(listTemp.toList());
    listTemp.clear();
  }
  print(list);
}
```

Result: 
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 3, 6, 9]]

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler version (No need to create temp list and then clear it):

```
void main() {
    List<List<int>> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        List<int> innerList = [];
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            innerList .add(i * j);
        }
        list.add(innerList );
    }
    print(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the list directly, either using `List.generate` or the new control flow literals in Dart 2.3

```
var list = List.generate(4, (i) => List.generate(4, (j) => i * j));
```

or

```
var list = [for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) [for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) i * j]];
```

The resulting lists are growable, in case you need to add more elements to existing sub-lists or add more sub-lists.